# Scale a JCheckBox box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox

I want to scale a `JCheckBox` e.g. equally to its set text's font size. For example when i increase the `Font` size the checkbox itself stays small but it should grow with the text or i want to set the size of the box myself:

```
JCheckBox chckbxTest = new JCheckBox("Test");
chckbxTest.setFont("Arial", Font.BOLD, 27));
```

If possible, I need the same functionality for `JRadioButton`. Unfortunately i haven't found any documentation regarding this functionality.

---

**Solution:**
The marked answer helped me to create a fully scalable own styled JCheckbox. The following example draws a simple rectangle filled with another rectangle when checked:

```
    [...]
     JCheckBox myCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Test");
     myCheckBox.setIcon(new SimpleCheckboxStyle(20));
    [...]

class SimpleCheckboxStyle implements Icon {

    int dim = 10;

    public SimpleCheckboxStyle (int dimension){
        this.dim = dimension;
    }

    protected int getDimension() {
        return dim;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component component, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ButtonModel buttonModel = ((AbstractButton) component).getModel();

        int y_offset = (int) (component.getSize().getHeight() / 2) - (int) (getDimension() / 2);
        int x_offset = 2;

        if (buttonModel.isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 60, 120));
        } else if (buttonModel.isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        }
        g.fillRect(x_offset, y_offset, fontsize, fontsize);
        if (buttonModel.isPressed()) {
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else if (buttonModel.isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(new Color(240, 240, 250));
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        g.fillRect(1 + x_offset, y_offset + 1, fontsize - 2, fontsize - 2);
        if (buttonModel.isSelected()) {
            int r_x = 1;
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(x_offset + r_x + 3, y_offset + 3 + r_x, fontsize - (7 + r_x), fontsize - (7 + r_x));
        }
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return getDimension();
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return getDimension();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice dynamic solution.

Comment: What is the `fontsize` variable that you use? I tried your code and the fontsize initialiazation was missing. Then I changed it in the constructor to get the dim value and it worked fine. Please let me know if this was right to do or if fontsize means something else and edit your post accordingly. Despite this, your code is really good and it helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example when i increase the Font size the checkbox itself stays small but it should grow with the text or i want to set the size of the box myself

Then you need to provide custom icons for the font size of your text. See methods like:

```
setIcon(....)
setSelectedIcon(...)
```

You would need to do the same for a JRadioButton. Also, you would need different icons for each LAF.

Comment: +1 It seems I misunderstood the question. Thought it was about the whole component size not just the icon.

Comment: Great, thanks. exactly what i needed. I add an full example above