# Change the size of a Swing checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am trying to make the checkbox bigger. It looks smaller according to the text. How can I do that?

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(new VisibleAction(name,renderer,i));
checkBox.setSelected(true);
renderer.setSeriesVisible(i, true);
checkBox.setFont(controlPanelFont);
```

Comment: I would try to set a bigger font. BTW, the renderer and VisibleAction in your code are irrelevant.

Comment: The only want to achieve that you want is to change the icon used by the checkbox, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807638/how-to-keep-jcheckbox-lf-as-in-enabledtrue-when-disabled/50807770#50807770)

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691353/scale-a-jcheckbox-box?rq=1